# Unable to return to cordova iOS app from google maps

Tags: ios, html, google-maps, cordova

I'm creating a cordova iOS application to be able to open up google maps.
Right now I use the code below to open up google maps from within my application.

`<a href='http://maps.google.com?saddr=lat,lng&daddr=lat,lng'>link</a>`

My issue is, my users will want to have a way to get back to my app.
Is there a way to put into my link parameters a way for google maps to know how to come back to my application? Something like a back button. I thought I saw somewhere something like this

`<a href='http://maps.google.com?saddr=lat,lng&daddr=lat,lng&x-success=sourceapp://?resume=true&x-source=AppName'>link</a>`

but tried with no success.